# Limpar body mantendo apenas 2 elementos

Tags: css, css3

Preciso excluir tudo do `body`, exceto **2 itens**.

Tentei das formas abaixo mas nenhuma funcionou:

```
  body > *:not("div#pedidosRelMensal, h1.resposta"){
    display: none;
  }

  body > *:not("div#pedidosRelMensal")not("h1.resposta"){
    display: none;
  }

  body > *:not(#pedidosRelMensal, h1.resposta){
    display: none;
  }
```

Se eu fizer apenas isso:

```
 body > *:not(#pedidosRelMensal){
    display: none;
  }
```

Vai de boa.

Mas preciso também do `h1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O correto seria concatenar os dois `:not():not()` e dentro do `not()` não se usa `""` no nome dos elementos.

```
body > *:not(#pedidosRelMensal):not(.resposta) {}
```

Dessa forma funciona

```css
body > *:not(#pedidosRelMensal):not(.resposta) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="pedidosRelMensal">
    div id pedidosRelMensal
</div>
<h1 class="resposta">H1 Resposta</h1>

<div>
    div qualquer
</div>
<h1>h1 qualquer</h1>
```

Outro jeito seria apagar tudo e depois voltar com o que vc precisa.

```css
body > *{
    display: none;
}
#pedidosRelMensal,
.resposta {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="pedidosRelMensal">
    div id pedidosRelMensal
</div>
<h1 class="resposta">H1 Resposta</h1>

<div>
    div qualquer
</div>
<h1>h1 qualquer</h1>
```

Comment: Seu chato, eu já estava respondendo.

Comment: kkkk, reponde ae tb @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss mas eu errei! :/ vou até editar...

Comment: Em CSS eu não saberia fazer, mas em JS eu faria assim: 
`let printContents = document.getElementById('print').innerHTML;
      document.body.innerHTML = printContents;`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss agora sim, concatenando os `:not():not()` um não anula o outro. Mas colabora ai, quanto mais melhor :d

Comment: Mas só consigo fazer pegando um elemento, não fiz ainda de pegar dois assim

Comment: @EdwardRamos com JS deve dar para fazer tranquilamente tb, o problema é que o JS barra o print da página, o CSS não, então na teoria para esse caso o CSS vai ser mais rápido que o JS. Com JS dependendo vc até poderia ver os elementos na tela por uma fração de segundo, antes deles desaparecerem

Comment: foma 1 resolveu para mim, Obrigado!

Comment: @CarlosRocha legal que resolveu ai! Boa sorte no projeto!

Comment: valeu, ficou pronto já. Só faltava isso! Mas vai fucionar só em localhost mesmo! Poderia ter feito ele em VisuaStudio ou Delphi., Mas para esse cliente preferi em PHP mesmo! Obrigado pela ajuda!